# How to change Default year(1900) of datepicker Dialog in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker, android-datepicker

Wanted to change default year of min date 1900 to 1902.

Implementation:

```
 val date = SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse("01/01/1902")
 date?.let {
       datePicker?.datePicker?.minDate = date.time
 }
```

**Result : Setting up min year(1902) perfectly in Android 10 but for Android 7 it's setting up 1901.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:** Using [Calendar](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar) to set min date for DatePickerDialog.

```
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH)
calendar.set(1902, Calendar.JANUARY, 1)
datePicker.datePicker.minDate = calendar.time.time
```